# Ошибка при подключении к серверу

Tags: java, android

Вообщем есть приложение, оно отправляет запрос на сервер, получает ответ, нормально функционирует, но... при потере или отключении вай фая оно вылетает. Как сделать что бы оно не вылетало а просто приостанавливалось до следующего подключения к интернету?

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        while (true) {

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }
                return buffer.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (responseCode == 200) {


        } else {

        }
```

Comment: Без логов ошибки ничего не узнать

Comment: Дело в том что там ошибок то и нет

Comment: Выводите stacktrace в лог, вот и узнаете ошибки.

Comment: Судя по всему дело в том, что у вас стоит `return null;` слишком рано. Переместите эту строку ниже на одну скобку(за пределы цикла `while (true)`)